# Can someone please help me out in optimizing the below mysql stored procedure which is crashing my server

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, query-optimization

/* Below will fetch all completed task.*/

```
insert ignore into NodeInstanceLog_Dump
select  nil.id, nil.connection, nil.log_date, nil.externalId,
nil.nodeContainerId, nil.nodeId ,nil.nodeInstanceId,
coalesce(nil.nodename, nil3.name)nodename, nil.nodeType, nil.processId,
nil.processInstanceId , nil.referenceId, nil.slaCompliance, nil.sla_due_date,
        nil.type, nil.workItemId, 0 as activeStatus
    from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog nil
    inner join  bpm.VariableInstanceLog vil
             ON nil.processInstanceId=vil.processInstanceId
      and  vil.value='Success'
      and  vil.variableId in ('oltOrderStatus','orderStatus')
      and  nodeType='EndNode'
      and  type=0
    left join  
    (
        SELECT  distinct nil2.*,nil1.nodeName name
            from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog nil1 inner join
            (
                SELECT  max(convert(nodeinstanceid,signed))id,processInstanceId
                    from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog
                    where  nodetype='HumanTaskNode'group by processInstanceId
            )nil2  ON nil1.nodeinstanceid=nil2.id
              and  nil1.processInstanceId=nil2.processInstanceId
    )nil3  ON nil.processInstanceId=nil3.processInstanceId;
```

/* Below will fetch all aborted task.*/

```
insert ignore into NodeInstanceLog_Dump
select  nil.id, nil.connection, nil.log_date, nil.externalId,
nil.nodeContainerId, nil.nodeId ,nil.nodeInstanceId,
coalesce(nil.nodename, nil3.name)nodename, nil.nodeType, nil.processId,
nil.processInstanceId , nil.referenceId, nil.slaCompliance, nil.sla_due_date,
        nil.type, nil.workItemId, 0 as activeStatus
    from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog nil
    inner join  bpm.VariableInstanceLog vil
             ON nil.processInstanceId=vil.processInstanceId
      and  vil.value='Aborted'
      and  vil.variableId in ('oltOrderStatus','orderStatus')
      and  nodeType='EndNode'
      and  type=0
    left join  
    (
        SELECT  distinct nil2.*,nil1.nodeName name
            from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog nil1 inner join
            (
                SELECT  max(convert(nodeinstanceid,signed))id,processInstanceId
                    from  bpm.NodeInstanceLog
                    where  nodetype='HumanTaskNode'group by processInstanceId
            )nil2  ON nil1.nodeinstanceid=nil2.id
              and  nil1.processInstanceId=nil2.processInstanceId
    )nil3  ON nil.processInstanceId=nil3.processInstanceId;
```

(from comment)

```
Table:NodeInstanceLog Columns: 
id bigint(20) AI PK 
connection varchar(255) 
log_date datetime 
externalId varchar(255) 
nodeId varchar(255) 
nodeInstanceId varchar(255) 
nodeName varchar(255) 
nodeType varchar(255) 
processId varchar(255) 
processInstanceId bigint(20)
sla_due_date datetime 
slaCompliance int(11) 
type int(11) 
workItemId bigint(20) 
nodeContainerId varchar(255) 
referenceId bigint(20)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Do all those queries finish within 15 seconds before the next schedule runs? If not, might have to increase the time, if the next run may be causing the crash.

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for the comment if that’s the case ya we can try increasing the time as well but other than the schedule issue do you feel the queries we are using is perfectly fine?

Comment: Your code is almost unreadable. Separate the queries with whitespace, and wrap them so that they can be read without continuously scrolling looking distances left and right. I can't tell what this is doing, but dropping and recreating tables every fifteen seconds looks suspect to me.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular is right. If your SQL code isn't formatted to be readable you can't read it and reason about it. If your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) can't read your code neither can we. And, an event that runs really often that also creates or drops permanent tables is probably a bad design. At a minimum it needs some sort of protection against reentrancy. A table lock, maybe?  Every 15 seconds is far far too often to create  or drop permanent tables. Well designed database systems almost never create tables when running in production.

Comment: Please figure out which step is slow so we can focus on that.

Comment: I have pasted the query which we feel is causing the crash can you please help me on this and one more thing i am trying to format this query to look good but i couldnt achieve it can you please tell me how to achieve it here in stack overflow.

Comment: @BuvneshVenkatesan - Indent by 4 spaces.  Is `and  vil.value='Aborted'` the only difference?

Comment: Please qualify all columns with their table alias -- I can't tell, for example, which table `type` and `nodeType` are in.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these indexes may help:

```
NodeInstanceLog:  INDEX(processInstanceId)
NodeInstanceLog:  INDEX(nodeinstanceid,  nodeName, processInstanceId)
VariableInstanceLog:  INDEX(processInstanceId,  value, variableId)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

`max(convert(nodeinstanceid,signed))` -- Does this mean that `nodeinstanceid` is a `VARCHAR`, but needs to be compare as a number?  I recommend you find a way to store it in an `INT` or other type of numeric column; this may allow the query to run much faster.  Also, is that column in `NodeInstanceLog`?  Is it the `PRIMARY KEY`?  What indexes (including the PK) exists now for the tables?

To help readers understand the query, please use `ON` for specifying how the tables relate, use `WHERE` for filtering.

Please qualify all columns with their table alias -- I can't tell, for example, which table `type` and `nodeType` are in.  Hence, the `INDEX` recommendations above may not be complete.

Comment: Hi Rick Thanks for your comment, am sharing the node instance log table description Table:NodeInstanceLog

Columns:

id bigint(20) AI PK
connection varchar(255)
log_date datetime
externalId varchar(255)
nodeId varchar(255)
nodeInstanceId varchar(255)
nodeName varchar(255)
nodeType varchar(255)
processId varchar(255)
processInstanceId bigint(20)
sla_due_date datetime
slaCompliance int(11)
type int(11)
workItemId bigint(20)
nodeContainerId varchar(255)
referenceId bigint(20)

Comment: Hi Rick, Thank you so much for your response. Nope nodeinstanceid is not the primary key. And this is the table that came up with the product that we are using now. And as you are suggesting can you please suggest a way on how to handle this VARCHAR to INT conversion.

Comment: Are you sure all the values in the column are numeric?  A simple `ALTER` may suffice; it will take a long time if the table is big.